# How to convert .bok to .pdf file

Tags: pdf, conversion, file-conversion

Anyone have any idea how to convert a .bok file to .pdf? I'm clueless. I've tried googling it and have searched a great deal, but I've come up with nothing.

The issue is that I can't even open the file. I don't have access to TestGen.

Comment: What program made the .Bok file?

Comment: If it's from TestGen, then why not load it into TestGen and export the test(s) to PDF?

Comment: If the program that can open .BOK files can print, you can use a PDF printer.